# wp_usermeta key problem

Tags: database, forms, user-meta, user-registration, input

I am trying to add a meta key to wp_usermeta but it does not work at all. The key would get value from a checkbox. I used the code from Wordpress codex tutorial and it's not adding anything. I will show you the code (it's from a woocommerce file, but I am adding this as a standard WordPress user meta data, so it really does not matter). I checked the database and there is no 'giodo' meta key in wp_usermeta. Could anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php   
    //1. Add a new form element...
    add_action('register_form','myplugin_register_form');
    function myplugin_register_form (){
        $giodo = ( isset( $_POST['giodo'] ) ) ? $_POST['giodo']: '';
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="giodo"><?php _e('First Name','mydomain') ?><br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="giodo" id="giodo" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($giodo)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    //2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure giodo is required.
    add_filter('registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3);
    function myplugin_registration_errors ($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {

        if ( empty( $_POST['giodo'] ) )
            $errors->add( 'giodo_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.','mydomain') );

        return $errors;
    }

    //3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
    add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register');
    function myplugin_user_register ($user_id) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['giodo'] ) )
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'giodo', $_POST['giodo']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: The code adds the field to the registration form.  Do you see it during registration?  The meta data should show up for new users, existing users will not have it.

Comment: Yes, I see the field. There is not even a single key with the name 'giodo'. No users have this meta data applied to them. Neither old nor new ones.

Comment: Looking at your code, giodo does not seem to be initialized to any value.  You should view your html page when on the registration page.  If giodo is not set to any value, then it will not be saved as user meta data.